# Sum of odd integers $= x$

Tags: combinatorics

How many sums are there that add up to a whole number $x$, and are made of only odd numbers? Each number can be used more than once.

Comment: Does the order count? For instance, how many do you expect for $x=4$?

Comment: It is not clear what type of answer you expect. There is no simple formula for this.

Comment: For $x$=4, (1+1+1+1) and (1+3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question, so I'm not going to answer it, only describe how I **would** answer it.

First of all, let's get rid of those odd numbers, because they are a bore. It is obvious that if $x$ is odd, there have to be an odd number of terms in the sum, and if $x$ is even, there have to be an even number of terms. So let's each all odd [or even] number $n$ up to and including $x$, and answer the question "How many sums of $n$ odd numbers are there which add up to $x$?".

This is obviously identical to "How many sums of $n$ even numbers are there which add up to $x-n$?".

This is obviously identical to "How many sums of $n$ numbers are there which add up to $\frac{1}{2}(x-n)$?".

You may already know how to answer "How many sums of $n$ numbers are there which add up to $y$?". If not, the way to look at it is this:

1. Write out the $n$ numbers in unary, with commas in between. For instance, 1+4+2 would be 1,1111,11.
2. Note that there will always be $y+n-1$ symbols in the set; that $n-1$ of them must be commas; and that consecutive commas are allowed, since 0 is an allowable number.
3. So there are as many ways of arranging $n$ numbers that add up to $y$ as there are of picking $n-1$ comma positions out of $y+n-1$ possible positions.
4. That is, the answer to this part of the question is $\binom{y+n-1}{n-1}$.

Unstitching the argument and going backwards, you need to sum these binomials for all odd $n$ from $1$ to $x$ (if $x$ is odd) or for all even $n$ from $2$ to $x$ (if $x$ is even).

Which is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Wonderfully explained. I was struggling to find a starting point but this really helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about [partitions into odd parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts), which is the same as the number of partitions into distinct parts. The number is given in [OEIS A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009) and starts $$1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38, 46, 54, 64, 76, 89, 104, 122, 142$$   No simple formula is given.